# Float right div problem and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

Basically my problem is with the page at

http://wiki.diablocommunity.com/index.php?title=Tristram_Cathedral

Please see the screen shots below

[IE 7](http://www.free.nodespot.com/ie7.jpg)

[Firefox 3.5](http://www.free.nodespot.com/ff3.jpg)

I have a right floating div (shown in the screen shots as the blue crossed box).
This div is the problem. When its floated left or removed there is no problem

The problem is, in the IE 7 screen shot, the area shown with the red crossed box should be black like it is in the Firefox screen shot and how it is in Chrome.

Anyway to fix this or hack around it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to add `overflow: auto;` to `#mw_content`? I tested on IE8's compatibility mode and it should do the trick.

I basically use the advice from [this forum post](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/836611-float-breaking-out-box#post3345966). Alternatively you could `float:right;` `#mw_content` which is suggested by simonuk in [this other forum post](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3835329.htm).

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Adding 'overflow: auto; to #mw_content' works and also fixs a few of my other problems. Thanks again